# Oracle impdp : UDI-00013 Message 13 not found

Tags: database, oracle, impdp

Using Oracle impdp I'm getting error message:

> UDI-00013 Message 13 not found 
>   No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UDI

How can I correct this?

Comment: Which operating system are you running this on? It looks like you don't have ORACLE_HOME set, or exported.

Comment: HP-UX, ORACLE_HOME is set as far as I can see.

Comment: Depending on the shell, are you sure it's exported, not just set locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this error when your `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable is not set, or when it is set but not exported:

```
> unset ORACLE_HOME
> ORACLE_HOME=/dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0.BTSP2
> impdp
UDI-00013: Message 13 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UDI
UDI-00019: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

> export ORACLE_HOME
> impdp

Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Mar 6 12:16:51 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username:
```

If it's set, so you can see it with `echo` for example, make sure it is also exported with `export ORACLE_HOME`; you can also check which variables have been exported with `export | grep ORACLE`, so you can see if anything else is missing - maybe `ORACLE_SID` depending on your connect string.

These are usually set by an environment set-up script.

Comment: What could be the reason if `ORACLE_HOME` is exported and points to Oracle Client installation location, but the error still does not go away?